# Test the convergence of $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\log n)^{\log\log n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I know that $$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\log n)^{\log n}}$$ converges and hence applying the Comparison test, I get the ratio $$\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac{(\log n)^{\log n}}{(\log n)^{\log\log n}}.$$ What I want to know is whether $a_n/b_n$ is bounded above or not. Or is there different approach to solving this problem?

Comment: Cauchy's condensation test readily gives the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I should have searched before. The answer was [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321738/does-sum-n-3-infty-frac-1-log-n-log-logn-converge?rq=1). Sorry for redundancy.