# Prove that the sequence diverges $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{\log n}^{\log \log n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove that the sequence diverges $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{\log n}^{\log \log n}}$$
Here is what I have done:
$$a_n = \frac{1}{{\log n}^{\log \log n}}$$ tends to zero when n tends to infinity.
Also, we can write $a_n$ as $$a_n = \frac{1}{{\log n}^{\log \log n}} = \frac{1}{e^{(\log \log n)^2}}.$$
Next, I wanted to compare $a_n$ and $\frac{1}{n}$ and my question is can I somehow prove that following inequaliy is correct $$(\log \log n)^2< \log n$$

Comment: Let $N=\log\log n$. Can you show that $N^2<e^N$ for all $N$ large enough?

Comment: @nejimban I got it now, thank you!

Comment: $a_1$ is not well-defined.

Comment: @PhoemueX I edited it now!

Comment: This has been duplicated many, many times.  The specific approach you are attempting is completed in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/321754/148510).